# Conditionally Remove Values in an Vector Base on Previous Value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data-cleaning

I have a vector of 1-60 values, that could only be one of three values

For example:

```
x <- c("VAL1","VAL1","VAL1","VAL2","VAL2","VAL3","VAL3","VAL3","VAL3","VAL1")
```

I would like to condense this vector by removing values base on the previous value, ie. remove n+1 if n = n+1, but if n != n+1 return n and n+1

The desired output would look like this:

```
x <- c("VAL1","VAL2","VAL3","VAL1")
```

I think am going to need to use a for loop, checking where i matches i+1, but I am having trouble with the syntax

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rle` from `base R` instead of using a `for` loop

```
rle(x)$values
[1] "VAL1" "VAL2" "VAL3" "VAL1"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could apply this function across columns in a table? Like if the values were in 60 individual columns. I wrote a loop that does it, but I have a huge table and it is inefficient, so I would like to use an alternative

Comment: @ColleenJoan you can do `lapply(yourdata, function(x) rle(x)$values)`

Comment: `rle` doesn't work with `yearmon` object (`zoo` package)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use indexing

```
x[c(x[-1] != x[-length(x)], TRUE)]

[1] "VAL1" "VAL2" "VAL3" "VAL1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach is using `rle` (as done by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72265392/12158757)), or using the lagged difference by [@onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72265415/12158757).

If you want to have a practice of coding with `for` loops, you can try

```
res <- x[1]
for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] != x[i - 1]) {
        res <- append(res, x[i])
    }
}
```